# string to base64 bytes, exactly with the same literal chars

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, base64, literals

today I got stucked with the following issue. I can explain it better with the inverse purpose: Say we have the following base64-variable,

```
b64_var = b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
```

Imagine that what we want it's not to decode it into string object of python, namely,

```
base64.b64decode(b64_var).decode('utf-8')
>>> 'hello world'
```

but the literal equivalent characters in string instead,

```
repr( b64_var )[1:]
>>> 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
```

Ok, now it's my question. I want to build a function that performs just the opposite,

```
'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=' -> b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=' (base64-obj) ???
```

I got stucked, I don't know how to do it.. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Python 3, `b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='` isn't a `<base64_obj>`, it's a string of bytes also know as a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) object (or `bytesarray`).

Answer (score 0):

Is this doing what you want?

```
b64_var = b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='

print(repr(b64_var))            # b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
print(repr(b64_var)[1:])        # 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
print('b' + repr(b64_var)[1:])  # b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
```

Comment: Thank you @martineau for the try. Unfortunatelly my problem to be solved is preciselly the inverse. But you gave me the key clue: `b64_var` is just a `bytes class`, not special one exported from base64 module. I going to post the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, it was easier as I expected.

First I am going to try to clarify what actually I wanted to do,

```
str_var = 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='               # str_var: string  
b64_var = fun_str_2_b64samechars(str_var)  # b64_var: bytes (b64)
```

Console,

```
b64_var
>>>b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
```

My goal was to guess how to build that `fun_str_2_b64samechars` function. And here it is exactly `bytes(str_var,'utf-8')`,

```
bytes('aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=','utf-8')
>>>b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
```

Probably it was because I thought it was some kind of base64 class as long as I employed the base64 module (due to this I edited the title). Thanks for the help and I hope it could be useful for someone :)